# А это нормальная практика засовывать огромный javascript прямо в html-страницу?

Tags: best-practice, javascript, веб-дизайн, html

У меня есть часть javascipt-а написанная для google maps и часть для работы с web-socket-ами. Они передают переменные друг другу. Но если подключить два файла по-отдельности, то они не смогут передавать переменные без дополнительного посредника, не так ли? Т.е. стоит запихнуть все в html-страницу и абстрагироваться от громоздкости этого монстра?

Comment: > Но если подключить два файла по-отдельности, то они не смогут передавать переменные без дополнительного посредника, не так ли?

с чего бы?

> Т.е. стоит запихнуть все в html-страницу и абстрагироваться от громоздкости этого монстра?

И, как минимум, забыть про кэширование добрых килобайтов на клиенте

Comment: В дополнение ответа от @Fike:

    <script src='./s1.js'></script>
    <script src='./s2.js'></script>

ведет себя также, как и:

    <script>
        // content of ./s1.js
        // content of ./s2.js
    </script>

Comment: @Fike А не подскажете как это работает? Допустим, мне нужно вызвать функцию из другого файла, т.е. для этого браузер выстраивает объединенный документ из всех подключенных фалов?

Comment: @cadmy, у скриптов общая изначальная область видимости, грубо говоря, `window`. Объявленные в одном скрипте функции будут видны в другом (после их объявления, конечно).

Comment: > И, как минимум, забыть про кэширование добрых килобайтов на клиенте
@Fike Это значит что большая страница будет еще и тяжелее для обработки?

Comment: @cadmy, это значит, что клиент каждый раз будет тянуть много лишнего добра, которое у него могло оказаться уже после первой загрузки. Если хотите, чтобы клиент посещал больше одной страницы - не устраивайте такого.

Comment: @Fike С чем тогда может быть связана такая рекомендация?
>For the most part, I always tell you to place the JavaScript you want to run directly on the page it will run on, and that rule still holds true for more involved JavaScript.
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470901

Comment: > С чем тогда может быть связана такая рекомендация?

Не знаю, но а) человек все еще обсуждает браузеры каменного века, что настораживает

> <!-- hide script from old browsers

и б) вся остальная статья посвящена как раз тому, чтобы выносить все в отдельный файл (не знаю, как это можно было проигнорировать).

Comment: б) так он написал, что это special case only

Comment: @cadmy, посвежее - что именно?

P.S. метку поправьте, нет такого слова: "practi**s**e".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я могу предложить три книги, в которых описаны подходы внедрения JavaScript в HTML с их описанием. Помимо рассмотрения обычных <script>...<script> и <script src="..."/> можно найти описания еще неблокирующих техник.

1. Steve Souders - "Even Faster Web Sites", глава 4,5
2. Николас Закас - "JavaScript - оптимизация производительности", глава 1
3. Николас Закас - "Professional JavaScript for web developers", глава 2

Что дает встраивание кода прямо на страницу? Вы не делаете лишний запрос на скачку файла и ожидания его разбора. При этом браузер может блокировать выполнение других закачек. Для страниц которые посещают единожды, на которых много скриптов и много внешних файлов, это может быть лучше.

Что дает подключение внешнего файла? Кеширование, рефакторинг, заменяемость для многостраничных сайтов.

Цитата из последней книги:

> "INLINE CODE VERSUS EXTERNAL FILES"
>
> Although it’s possible to embed JavaScript in HTML files directly, it’s generally 
> considered a best practice to include as much JavaScript as possible using external 
> files. Keeping in mind that there are no hard and fast rules regarding this practice, 
> the arguments for using external files are as follows:
>
> ➤ Maintainability — JavaScript code that is sprinkled throughout various HTML pages turns code maintenance into a problem. It is much easier to have a directory for all JavaScript files so that developers can edit JavaScript code independent of the markup in which it’s used.
>
> ➤ Caching — Browsers cache all externally linked JavaScript files according to specific settings, meaning that if two pages are using the same file, the file is downloaded only once. This ultimately means faster page-load times.
>
> ➤ Future-proof — By including JavaScript using external files, there’s no need to use the XHTML or comment hacks mentioned previously. The syntax to include external files is the same for both HTML and XHTML.

В общем-то для любого проекта, который не является маленьким, лучше использовать внешние скрипты.

Answer (score 5):

В дополнение к ответу Alex Krass:

Есть популярная практика — определять в серверном шаблоне нужный для корректной работы логики javascript у конкретного пользователя/сессии/региона набор конфигурационных параметров, и этот набор подставляют перед загрузкой основного javascript-файла/файлов в виде инлайн-скрипта. Очень грубый пример: `<script>app.config = { userId: 13, geoId: 23, role: 'member'}; </script><script src="app.js"></script>`. Да, подобный инлайн-скрипт будет выполняться синхронно (браузер будет заблокирован на время выполнения), но скрипт весьма простой и маленький, потому блокировка не повлияет практически нисколько на производительность.

Этой практике есть более красивая альтернатива — подгружать конфигурационные параметры в сериализованном в JSON виде в script type=text/plain: `<script type="text/plain">{'userId': '13', 'geoId': '23', 'role': 'member' }</script>` — этот вариант даже несколько лучше, так как не требует браузер распарсить указанный код (из-за type=text/plain), но конфигурацию придётся парсить уже самому в javascript.

Также хочется отметить, что разрешённые к выполнению инлайн-скрипты представляют собой потенциальную угрозу [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), и хорошей практикой является внедрение [Content-Security-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) в параноидальном режиме, где выполнение инлайн-скриптов по умолчанию выключено, а подгрузка внешних javascript-файлов разрешена только с определённых узлов.

То есть, отвечая на вопрос изначальный: нет, класть весь код js-логики внутрь html-страницы — это по умолчанию ненормально, также это относительно небезопасно, чаще всего плохо сказывается на производительности и стоимости обслуживания.

При этом вопрос влияния расположения javascript во внешнем файле или в инлайн-скрипте на общую производительность страницы иногда требует тщательного рассмотрения и расчёта баланса между кучей взаимовлияющих переменных:

1. средним временем ЦА (целевой аудитории) на DNS resolve time для узла, где располагаются внешние js-файлы
2. среднем RTT (Round Trip Time) ЦА для TCP-соединения до узла с js-файлами
3. присутствием https (+3 roundtrip'a) или его отсутствием
4. наличием / отсутствием возможности CDN использовать
5. влиянием js на DOM (можно ли включить defer и использовать уже горячее TCP-соединение с большим wnd для отдачи внешнего js-файла — это при условии отдачи js-файла с того же хоста, что и html)
6. средней прогретостью кэша у ЦА

и многими-многими другими параметрами (это только что в голову сразу пришло).

Answer (score 4):

Нормальная, если используемые скрипты используются только на этой странице сайта. Например, для сайта-одностраничника.

**Выигрыш**: меньше HTTP запросов.

**Недостаток**: вы отказываетесь от асинхронной загрузки скриптов. Можно было бы показать уже что-то юзеру, не дожидась полной загрузки.

К [области видимости](http://habrahabr.ru/post/78991/) в JavaScript ваш вопрос не имеет никакого отношения.